# how to delete category when there is no delete option?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a root category and under this, 7 subcategories are there. I wanted to delete some subcategories.So I took the help of delete option from top right corner and delete that category.However one subcategory doesn't have "delete" option. Now I wonder how can I delete that. I have no use of that subcategory now. So can anybody tell how to do that ? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Delete button is the best way to delete a subcategory,If the delete button is not there some thing wrong in your admin panel.

But you can deactivate that subcategory by selecting `Is Active *` drop down to `No`
and by selecting `Include in Navigation Menu *` drop down also to `No`
so the subcategory is not active and not included in any menus.

**Update**

you can remove it from table.To do that you can write an installer script(Upgrade).

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'your_category_id');
```

**Update 2**

You can refer this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/) to learn how to write installer scripts.

You can refer this [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/magento-install-upgrade-data-scripts-explained/) also.

Comment: Thanks  @mujas. I have already done that. But I want to completely remove that subcategory. As I have told no delete option is there for that subcategory only. Is there any way to resolve it ?

Comment: check the update

Comment: Where should I write the installer script and how to run it ?

Comment: check the update 2